# Why SimpleDateFormat needs timezone setting for parsing time in UTC

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have next dateTime represented as String: `"2015-08-21T22:00:00Z"` and if I try to parse it with SimpleDateFormat without setting timezone I am receiving strange value:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
sdf.parse("2015-08-21T22:00:00Z") // Fri Aug 21 22:00:00 CEST 2015
```

It looks like it ignores Z - UTC designator.
On the other hand when I set GMT timezone eveything is working as expected:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
sdf.parse("2015-08-21T22:00:00Z") // Sat Aug 22 00:00:00 CEST 2015
```

Why it is working in that way? Why I need to set timezone for SimpleDateFormat even that string contains UTC designator?

Comment: @Tunaki: That's actually the answer. Feel free to post it as such :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes in a `SimpleDateFormat` string imply that they are string literals. You've correctly escaped 'T', but by wrapping Z you've told Java to ignore that value. Remove the quotes, or else set the timezone manually as you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you didn't tell `SimpleDateFormat` that the String had a UTC designator (you escaped it with `'Z'`).

According to [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Javadoc, [ISO 8601 format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone) is obtained with the `X` pattern. The following will therefore provide the correct output:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
sdf.parse("2015-08-21T22:00:00Z"); // Sat Aug 22 00:00:00 CEST 2015
```